# Why is transaction logic commented out in baasbox DbHelper.java?

Tags: transactions, orientdb, mbaas

I have been working with baasbox lately and was wondering why has the transaction logic been commented out in the baasbox DbHelper.java file.

```
public static void commitTransaction(){
    ODatabaseRecordTx db = getConnection();
    if (isInTransaction()){
        if (Logger.isTraceEnabled()) Logger.trace("Commit transaction");
        //db.commit();
    }
}
```

Check here for the complete code:
https://github.com/baasbox/baasbox/blob/master/app/com/baasbox/db/DbHelper.java

Other orientdb transaction logic is also commented out, like db.begin() and db.rollback().

Wouldn't functions like delete(ORid) in NodeDao.java absolutely require this transaction logic? If yes, then how is it working correctly currently?

Can someone provide any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm a BaasBox engineer.

The BaasBox project started when OrientDB was very young and transactions management was painful.
We created helper methods to easily support transactions in the future.
We then shifted our focus on features, performance and responsiveness.

In the near future we have in our roadmap to upgrade the DB engine to OrientDB 1.7.x that has better transactions support and other interesting features, so we plan to "reactivate" the transaction logic as soon as possible, consistently with other priorities.

Comment: Isn't it incorrect to not have transactions in that codepath? What about synchronization problems there?